# PHP/Cron Limit Number of Concurrently Running Scripts

Tags: php, cron

I have a script written in PHP that is kicked off by a cron job. It's a long running script, and often cron kicks off another instance before the last is finished. That's fine. I allow 3 instances of this script to run at any given time.

I limit the script to 3 instances with this code at the top of the script:

```
exec('ps -A | grep nameofmyscript', $results);
if (count($results) > 4) {
    echo "Already Running\n"
    die(0);
}
```

It works, but I'm looking for a better way. This approach backfired on me a few weeks back when I renamed the script, and forgot to change that line of code. It also fails when the script is named something similar to an already running process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP, you could create a randomly named lock file in a directory specific to the cron job. Check for the number of lock files that exist in the directory before letting the PHP script continue.  This may not be the best solution though.

Comment: It's not a bad approach. The only drawback is I'd need another periodically running script that cleans up orphaned pid files. PHP (or any language for that matter) doesn't always shut down cleanly.

Comment: @mellowsoon: check the file modified time, if bigger than 5 minutes delete de PID. (time() - filemtime($path) > 5*60)

Answer (score 1):

You could automate the name placement...

```
exec('ps -A | grep ' . escapeshellarg(basename(__FILE__)) , $results);
if (count($results) > 4) {
    echo "Already Running\n"
    die(0);
}
```

Comment: That's a better approach than my current solution. I'd probably have to use basename(__FILE__), since the full path isn't included in the ps output. However it still doesn't prevent collisions with similarly named scripts running on the system.

Comment: @mellowsoon Ah yes, `basename()` would be better, I forgot :P. If you show me output of `ps -A`, I'll write you a regular expression that should match your PHP file perfectly.

Comment: @alex, okay. Assume the full path to the script is /home/mellowsoon/myscript.

Comment: @mellowsoon So `/home/mellowsoon/myscript` is what is in `ps`? What does `__FILE__` give you?

Comment: @alex, in ps it would simply be myscript. Which is the problem. There may be another executable on the system called myscriptfoo, or even myscript.

Comment: @mellowsoon Match the entire path, and use a regular expression with `grep` and use `$` and `m` modifier to make it match the end of the lines.

Comment: @alex, unfortunately ps doesn't return the full path of the running program. All I can match is the exact name of the script, and it may match other processes running with the same name.

Comment: Not sure about `grep` (don't use it often), but write a regex like this `/your_program.php$/m`. That will match your program immediately before a newline. Sorry I'm a bit of a *nix noob ;)